# What fantastical/fairy tale creatures are associated with 'doing the work behind the scenes'?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

In some fairy tales little dwarfs/elfs/pixies/??? perform some work on behalf of the protagonist. Santa Claus has his elf helpers who, at least in some cultures, manufacture the toys. Is there a joke/humorous phrase in everyday english about a task being done by those creatures, used when wishing to either abstract away or keep the person(s) responsible secret? If so, is the mental association strong enough that even their name only brings this particular context to mind?
Not my case, but, for example, hanging out a sign/note 'pixies(?)' on the doors in an office as an allusion to doing the real work without receiving recognition?

This is certainly a cultural thing, but considering that fairy tales are pretty much shared between all but all european countries without much variation, I suspect that such an idiom/association exists.

Comment: I can only think of the Grimm story called in English 'The Elves and the Shoemaker', but elves have so many other associations (including Tolkien's version) that the word certainly wouldn't suggest that story in particular.

Comment: Yeah. Tolkien spelling is different, so at least if you read his books they register as two different things, but there are those who are not and even in the original spelling I suspect it's closer to fae than that fable.

Comment: The British TV series QI features "elves" who do the behind-the-scenes work (mainly research). Elves are certainly a possibility but there are many different kinds of elves (Tolkien's elves don't particularly reflect traditional European folklore so they're probably not the best example, although they have been influential since; Wikipedia says he was originally going to make the elves fairies but that word has connotations of homosexuality https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elf_(Middle-earth) ).